# Zoom product in WooCommerce site is cropped into small size and is shown in a corner

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zooming

I am working on a WooCommerce site, I uploaded product images on localhost and are working fine. Now when I set the site to live server, I am facing an issue that when I upload a new product, the image is shown in a corner having size of 148x200. The products which were uploaded locally are working fine but issue is in new products pictures?

This is the code when I inspect the product

```
href="http://www.jemisonleather.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG-20160315-WA0034-148x200.jpg" itemprop="image" class="yith_magnifier_zoom woocommerce-main-image" title="IMG-20160315-WA0034"><img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.jemisonleather.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG-20160315-WA0034-600x600.jpg" class="attachment-shop_single size-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="IMG-20160315-WA0034" srcset="http://www.jemisonleather.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG-20160315-WA0034-600x600.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" src-orig="http://www.jemisonleather.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG-20160315-WA0034-600x600.jpg">
```

And this code is shown when hover on the product:

```
style="left: 335px; top: 0px; width: 335px; height: 335px; display: block; background-image: url("http://www.jemisonleather.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG-20160315-WA0034-148x200.jpg"); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"
```

Here the image of size 148x200 is picked, while on localhost the original is picked in the url: `(IMG-20160315-WA0034)`